# Can a functor $ F: A\to B$ not map $A$ to a subcategory of $B$?

Tags: category-theory

So, I'm studying Category Theory, and I'm stuck with some questions. One of them is this one:

Can a functor $F:A \to B$, meaning, a functor $F$ from category $A$ to category $B$, have an image that is NOT a subcategory of $B$?

I can't really find a situation where this happens, but by my readings this is wrong of my part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this can happen.  The trick is that there might be morphisms which are not composable in $A$, but their image in $B$ is composable, and so the image of $F$ need not contain the composition of their images.

Here's a specific example.  Let $A$ have four objects objects $a,b,c$ and $d$, with only two morphisms besides the identity, a morphism $f:a\to b$ and a morphism $g:c\to d$.  Let $B$ have three objects $x,y,z$ with non-identity maps $h:x\to y$, $i:y\to z$, and $j:x\to z$, with $j=ih$.  Define a functor $F:A\to B$ by $F(a)=x$, $F(b)=F(c)=y$, $F(d)=z$, $F(f)=h$, and $F(g)=i$.  Then the image of $F$ is not a subcategory, because it contains $h$ and $i$ but not $ih=j$.

Comment: +1. Note for the OP that if $F$ is injective on objects, then this can't happen and the image of $F$ is indeed a subcategory.

Comment: Ok, but if the image does not contain ih, would it be a category at all? I mean, as far as I understand, a category must have the compositions of its morfisms.

Comment: Right, the image isn't even a category at all.

Comment: Nice. Thank you Eric for the complete explanation, and you too Noah for pointing the inejctive part.