# The image of a functor need not be a subcategory

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples, functors

[Warning 1.2.19](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) gives an example when the image of a functor is not a subcategory:

[image]

But I'm confused: the author defines a functor $F$ right away without saying what the codomain category is. This causes the question: the image of that functor is not subcategory of which category? If the codomain is the category depicted on the right (which is the same as the image of $F$), then that is a subcategory of itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Functor F:A -> B not map to a subcategory of B?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901777/can-a-functor-fa-b-not-map-to-a-subcategory-of-b)

Comment: @GuidoA.I don't think it's a duplicate since the OP is not looking for an example but asking about a particular example that (s)he doesn't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The codomain is the category depicted on the right, and the image of $F$ is not a subcategory because it contains the morphisms $p$ and $q$ but not their composition $qp$. This is explained under the diagram.

Comment: The image is not a subcategory because the image is not even a category. Being a category requires the composition to exist. Am I right?

Comment: @XYSquared Yes, you are.